# Удалять каждый li по номеру

Tags: html, jquery

Есть код

```
<button onclick="$('#aside-history .list-history li:nth-child($count)').remove();">×</button>
```

Необходимо, чтобы вместо $count подставлялся номер li элемента, на который произошло нажатие.

Comment: а зачем вам подставлять какое то значение $count и после удалять ?

Comment: Весь код codeshare.io/aVmmwz Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, т.е необходимо удалить элемент на который нажали, лучше сделать так:

> UPD

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.button_con button').on('click', function () {
 var key = $(this).index() + 1;
 $('#aside-history .list-history li:nth-child(' + key + ')').remove();
});

});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="aside-history">
  <ul class="list-history">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="button_con">
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
  <button>×</button>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

$('.button_con button').on('click', function () {
 var key = $(this).index() + 1;
 $('#aside-history .list-history li:nth-child(' + key + ')').remove();
});

});
ругается prntscr.com/ir1sqw

Comment: Ну наверно при копирования кода что то не скопировали, например кавычку ))

Comment: Весь код https://codeshare.io/aVmmwz Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

> li элемента, на который произошло нажатие

```
$(event.target).closest("li").remove()
```

Comment: почему не `this` а `event.target`?

Comment: Наверное, this тоже можно, но зависит от того, где обработчик висит. Последнее время на jQuery не пишу, так что первым в голову именно target пришёл.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ir1sqw начинает ругаться